# what is the best way to use sass in a sinatra application?

Tags: dart, sass, sinatra

I'm writing a small Sinatra project, using rack and a Gemfile for hosting on Heroku. In order to use sass, I wanted to  add  `gem 'sass', '~> 3.7', '>= 3.7.4'` to my Gemfile and then add this to config.ru

```
require 'sass/plugin/rack'
use Sass::Plugin::Rack
```

I turns out that the sass gem is deprecated, as per this information: https://github.com/sass/ruby-sass, saying we should use `libsass` . That would mean that I need to add `gem 'sassc', '~> 2.4'` to the Gemfile ... I haven't figured out yet how and where add this line so my Sinatra app knows is should use libsass - any help would be much appreciated:

```
SassC::Engine.new(sass, style: :compressed).render
```

Now, it turns out that `libsass` is also deprecated, and the Sass blog recommends using `dart sass` as per this post https://sass-lang.com/blog/libsass-is-deprecated. I didn't find any information (yet) on how to implement dart sass in a ruby project, or Sinatra specifically.

So now I'm puzzled. What to use and how?

Comment: Have you considered using webpack or more simply using the dart scss cli directly to watch for file changes? https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/dart-sass